# Error handling in teradata SP

Tags: error-handling, exception, teradata

I used to get the **ERROR_NUMBER** and **ERROR_MESSAGE** using the following code:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLException
     BEGIN

        ROLLBACK/ABORT;
        SET ERROR_MESSAGE = TMPMSG;
        SET ERROR_NUMBER = SQLCODE;
        OPEN cur1;
        LEAVE #MAIN#;
     END;
```

**Updated:**

```
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLException
     BEGIN
        ROLLBACK/ABORT;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 ErrMsg_value = MESSAGE_TEXT ;   
        SET ErrCode_value = SQLCODE ;
     end;
```

But I need the following information as well:

```
 ERROR_SEVERITY
 ERROR_STATE
 ERROR_PROCEDURE
 ERROR_LINE
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What is `TMPMSG`? Only `SQLCODE` is a builtin variable. You better use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` to get error info.

Comment: Ok, please see the updated content..just like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an exception causes a rollback there's probably no need for ABORT (unless in some cases when you run an ANSI mode session). If you need it it should be done after the GET DIAGNOSTICS as it resets the diagnostic area.

- `ERROR_SEVERITY`: There's no severity (only BTEQ supports this concept)
- `ERROR_STATE`,`ERROR_PROCEDURE`,`ERROR_LINE`: Those variables are SQL Server syntax, they don't exist in Standard SQL/Teradata SQL.